# Django will not redirect to 404 in try except statement

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm currently in the process of learning the Django library and am stumped
because I am receiving a DoesNotExist error (status = 500) instead of a 404 page error,
I tried turning debug = False, however all I received was a 500 status page instead.

```
class CategoryView(generic.ListView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'rango/category.html'
    allow_empty = False

    try:
        def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
            context = super(CategoryView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
            category_name = decode_url(self.kwargs['category_name_url'])
            category = Category.objects.get(name = category_name)
            pages = Page.objects.filter(category = category)
            context['category'] = category
            context['pages'] = pages
            return context   
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
```

Traceback:

> DoesNotExist at /rango/category/Perl/
>
> Category matching query does not exist.
>
> Traceback: File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in
>   get_response
>     114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in
>   view
>     69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in
>   dispatch
>     87.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs) File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py" in
>   get
>     152.         context = self.get_context_data() File "/Users/justahack/Documents/Python/tango_with_django_project/rango/views.py"
>   in get_context_data
>     47.             category = Category.objects.get(name = category_name) File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in get
>     151.         return self.get_queryset().get(*args, **kwargs) File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
>     307.                 self.model._meta.object_name)
>
> Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /rango/category/Perl/ Exception Value:
>   Category matching query does not exist.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that try/except block is outside the method and it cannot catch the exception inside. To fix it, put try/except into the method:

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(CategoryView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    category_name = decode_url(self.kwargs['category_name_url'])

    # HERE
    try:
        category = Category.objects.get(name = category_name)
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    pages = Page.objects.filter(category = category)
    context['category'] = category
    context['pages'] = pages
    return context
```

Also, there is a nicer way to throw `404` if the object doesn't exist - use [get_object_or_404()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) shortcut:

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(CategoryView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    category_name = decode_url(self.kwargs['category_name_url'])
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, name = category_name)
    pages = Page.objects.filter(category = category)
    context['category'] = category
    context['pages'] = pages
    return context
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I decided to go with the nicer way you suggested. I am always looking to do things in a nicer, cleaner way.

Comment: What is `Http404` and where do I import it from?

Comment: @User try `from django.http import Http404`.

Answer (score 1):

There is also an easier way instead of using `try ... except`: You can import `get_object_or_404` from `django.shortcuts` and your code would be like this:

```
category = get_object_or_404(Category, name=category_name)
```

This will throw a 404 if object does not exist.